# Why weight of a monomial $X_1^{v_1}\cdots X_n^{v_n}$ is defined as $v_1+2v_2+\cdots + nv_n$, but not $v_1+\cdots+v_n$?

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

I was looking the proof of fundamental theorem on symmetric polynomials from Lang's Algebra (see [this, p.190-192](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Fge-BwqhqIYC&pg=PA190&lpg=PA190&dq=symmetric%20polynomials%20Lang&source=bl&ots=IMygTdF7A1&sig=Xyg7MISYH2pLC9g1NExFgEicNkk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGuPW2_N3NAhXDkpQKHeEBC8YQ6AEILjAE#v=onepage&q=symmetric%20polynomials%20Lang&f=false)). I didn't understood one thing from *proof* and one question came to mind from *statement of theorem*.

> [image]
>   [image]

**Question 1.** Why weight of the monomial  $X_1^{v_1}\cdots X_n^{v_n}$ is defined as $v_1+2v_2+\cdots + nv_n$, instead of just $v_1+v_2+\cdots + v_n$? I think, even-though we define this way - $v_1+v_2+\cdots + v_n$ - then still induction argument may work in the proof. .

**Question 2.** In statement of Theorem 6.1, it is said that $g$ is of degree *at most* degree of $f$. My question is that, isn't it necessary that $g$ should of degree *equal to* $d$? What is example in this case?

Comment: I would need to take a closer look at the proof to see precisely how it is used. But just taking the sum is already the degree. What we want is a way to separate various ways the same degree can arise, to get a stronger ordering.

Comment: I added image file of proof.

Comment: I think, as soon as the proof reaches to $f_1=s_nf_2(t_1,\cdots,t_n)$ then the degree of $f_2$ (being maximum degree of its monomial -in the sense $v_1+\cdots + v_n$ -) is smaller than that of $f_1$, hence induction is applicable.

Comment: Maybe the induction will work, but the resulting conclusion will be weaker than Lang's since your weight $\leq$ his weight. In some sense you shouldn't have to go to higher degrees to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the conclusion of the theorem is: $f(t) = g(s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_n)$, where we have substituted $s_i$ for $X_i$.  The polynomial $s_i$ is the elementary symmetric polynomial of degree $d$, so $X_i$ should have a weight of $d$, so that the weight of $g$ before substitution will match the degree of $g$ after substitution.  The purpose of the weights is to keep track of what the resulting degree of $g$ will be, before you actually make the substitution.